# RxJS combineLatest: Unable to merge with latest values in Angular 12

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have 3 filter values (select boxes basically). When there is a selection change, I want to fire a combined API call along with other filter values selected previously (using BehaviorSubject for each filter). Unfortunately, in the 'combineLatest' I can see only 1 filter value. Other values from other subjects are disappearing. Please help me understand where am i going wrong:

**Service:**

```ts
private typeFilterSubject = new BehaviorSubject('');
typeFilterObs$ = this.typeFilterSubject.asObservable();

private priceFilterSubject = new BehaviorSubject('');
priceFilterObs$ = this.priceFilterSubject.asObservable();

private brandFilterSubject = new BehaviorSubject('');
brandFilterObs$ = this.brandFilterSubject.asObservable();

updateTypeFilter(filter) {
  this.typeFilterSubject.next(filter);
}
updatePriceFilter(filter) {
  this.priceFilterSubject.next(filter);
}
updateBrandFilter(filter) {
  this.brandFilterSubject.next(filter);
}

getData$ = combineLatest([
  this.typeFilterObs$,
  this.priceFilterObs$,
  this.brandFilterObs$
]).pipe(
  switchMap(([type, price,brand]) => {
    console.log([type, price, brand]);

    // here i am getting ["electronics","",""]
    // or [14, "", ""] or ["IKEA", "", ""]
    // instead of ["electronics", 14, "IKEA"]

    return this._http.get<IProduct[]>(
      `http://localhost:3000/products?type=${type}&price=${price}&brand=${brand}`
    );
  })
);
```

**Component -1 : from where 'next' is fired**

```ts
onTypeChanged() {
  this._appService.updateTypeFilter(this.typeSelected) //"Electronics"
}

onBrandChanged() {
  this._appService.updateTypeFilter(this.brandSelected) //"IKEA"
} 

onPriceChanged() {
  this._appService.updateTypeFilter(this.priceSlected) //14
}
```

**component 2 - from where I am subscribing to the combined data**

```ts
this.getData = this._appService.getData$
```

Comment: I guess that, once you subscribe to the combineLatest, it doesn’t fire again as there is no changing value anymore in comp2..?

Comment: I was calling the same function for every filter change :) And I think the behavior you are talking about is for forkJoin. combineLatest has to fire for every change in any observable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it,

Just had to make change in component 1, I was calling the "updateTypeFilter" for all filters. Lol.

```
 onTypeChanged() {
    this._appService.updateTypeFilter(this.typeSelected)
  }

  onBrandChanged() {
    this._appService.updateBrandFilter(this.brandSelected)
  }

  onPriceChanged() {
    this._appService.updatePriceFilter(this.priceSlected)
  }
```